# Advanced Query Logic With Multiple Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a page on my site that acts as a search tool/search results page for users to find rental spaces. On the left side is a column of checkboxes that let the user filter the results by three separate custom taxonomies (`space-types`, `space-features`, `space-areas`) the right side of the page lists the results after the checkbox form is submitted.

I am trying to properly query the spaces (custom post type `space-listings`) based on the selected terms in each taxonomy but the logic doesn't seem to be possible and I'm not sure how else to do it.

This is the needed logic:
If the space listing has ANY of the `space-types` and ALL of the `space-features` that the user has selected AND has ANY of the `space-areas` that they have selected.

Here is the closest I've gotten with my query array:

```
$searchspace = array (
'post_type'=>'space_listing',
'posts_per_page'=> 3,
'paged' => $paged,
'tax_query'=> array (
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'space-types',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $searchedtypes, //Array of selected types
                    'operator' => 'IN'//default
        ),
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'space-features',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $searchedfeatures, //Array of selected features
                    'operator' => 'AND'
        ),
            array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'space-areas',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $searchedareas, //Array of selected areas
                    'operator' => 'IN'//default
        ),
    )

);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in Codex.

First — areas should probably be in your `tax_query` as well.

Second — you probably need to make use of `operator` argument in queries (inner ones). I am not sure without testing this out but `AND` seems like it would for more strict matches than default `IN` for your mandatory types/features logic.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about the operator perameter. I've edited the question (and the logic, which I typed wrong) with what I think should work. Going to test and see if I'm right.

Comment: @Eckstein does the query not work after the edit?

Comment: I'm still having trouble with it, but I'm not sure exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Nevermind, it was something elsewhere in my code. This works perfectly.